# Unable to update/replace group values within Loop (Python, "AttributeError: can't set attribute")

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, replace

## Unable to replace the values of group with new values (within a loop)

I have seen *somewhat* similar issues with the same error code where they mention a "property" and the need for a "setter", but I do not believe this is applicable/the easiest way to solve my particular issue.

- I believe there is a much simpler solution with maybe `.merge`,`.transform`,a `lambda`, or even a simple `=` assignment...
- Furthermore, my issue arises within a loop and groupby group, making it even more different from other problems with similar error messages

#### Getting "`AttributeError: can't set attribute`"

DataFrame:

```
sample_data = [['USA', 'gdp', 2001, 10],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2001, 100],['USA', 'people', 2001, 1000],['USA', 'dragons', 2001, 3],['CHN', 'gdp', 2001, 12], ['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2001, 120],['CHN', 'people', 2001, 2000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2001, 1],['RUS', 'gdp', 2001, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2001, 105], ['RUS', 'people', 2001, 1500],['RUS', 'dragons', 2001, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2002, 12],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2002, 105],['USA', 'people', 2002, 1200], ['USA', 'dragons', 2002, np.nan],['CHN', 'gdp', 2002, 14],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2002, 127],['CHN', 'people', 2002, 3100],['CHN', 'dragons', 2002, 4], ['RUS', 'gdp', 2002, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2002, 99],['RUS', 'people', 2002, 1600],['RUS', 'dragons', 2002, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2003, 15], ['USA', 'avgIQ', 2003, 115],['USA', 'people', 2003, 2000],['USA', 'dragons', 2003, np.nan],['CHN', 'gdp', 2003, 16],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2003, 132], ['CHN', 'people', 2003, 4000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2003, 6],['RUS', 'gdp', 2003, 11],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2003, 108],['RUS', 'people', 2003, 2000], ['RUS', 'dragons', 2003, np.nan],['USA', 'gdp', 2004, 18],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2004, 111],['USA', 'people', 2004, 2500],['USA', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['CHN', 'gdp', 2004, 18],['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2004, 140],['CHN', 'people', 2004, np.nan],['CHN', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['RUS', 'gdp', 2004, 15],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2004, 103],['RUS', 'people', 2004, 2800],['RUS', 'dragons', 2004, np.nan], ['USA', 'gdp', 2005, 23],['USA', 'avgIQ', 2005, 111],['USA', 'people', 2005, 3700],['USA', 'dragons', 2005, 8],['CHN', 'gdp', 2005, 22], ['CHN', 'avgIQ', 2005, 143],['CHN', 'people', 2005, 6000],['CHN', 'dragons', 2005, 15],['RUS', 'gdp', 2005, 17],['RUS', 'avgIQ', 2005, np.nan], ['RUS', 'people', 2005, 3000],['RUS', 'dragons', 2005, 3]]

sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_data, columns = ['A','B','C','D'])

sample_df['C'] = sample_df['C'].astype(float) 
sample_df.head()
```

[image]

```
Data columns (total 4 columns):
A    60 non-null object
B    60 non-null object
C    60 non-null float64
D    50 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
```

```
from impyute.imputation.cs import mice
```

> ### The following line within the Loop is the problem:
>
> `group['D'].values = ((mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))[1]).values`
>
> #### Note the hashtags I placed in the output.

```
for group_index, group in sample_group:

    if group.isnull().values.any() == True:

        print(group)
        print(group['D'].values)
        print(mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))
        print((mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))[1])
        print(((mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))[1]).values)


        group['D'].values = ((mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))[1]).values


        print(group)


    else:
        print('Checked group but could not satisfy condition', group_index)
```

```
Checked group but could not satisfy condition ('CHN', 'avgIQ')  #Does not have any nan values
      A        B        C     D
7   CHN  dragons 2,001.00  1.00
19  CHN  dragons 2,002.00  4.00
31  CHN  dragons 2,003.00  6.00
43  CHN  dragons 2,004.00   nan   #Prints group because it has nan
55  CHN  dragons 2,005.00 15.00
[ 1.  4.  6. nan 15.]             #Prints values of 'D'
         0     1
0 2,001.00  1.00
1 2,002.00  4.00
2 2,003.00  6.00
3 2,004.00 10.86                  #Imputes the nan value and prints
4 2,005.00 15.00
0    1.00
1    4.00
2    6.00
3   10.86                         #Prints only the column with the new imputed value
4   15.00
Name: 1, dtype: float64
[ 1.          4.          6.         10.85714286 15.        ] #Prints the new values for the column





**AttributeError: can't set attribute**
```

#### Desired Output (After the outputs that currently work^^^):

```
      A        B        C     D
7   CHN  dragons 2,001.00  1.00
19  CHN  dragons 2,002.00  4.00
31  CHN  dragons 2,003.00  6.00
43  CHN  dragons 2,004.00 10.86   #Replace the original 'D' column for that group, with the new value(s)
55  CHN  dragons 2,005.00 15.00
```

Eventually I will want to create a new df that has all the original groups without nans, with the updated groups where the nans have been imputed.

Comment: Thanks for any and all input

Comment: TLDR; what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @Kevin resolved it. TLDR; was trying to replace a group's column values with new values, and had `group['D'].values = ` where it should have simply been `group['D']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
group['D'] = ((mice(group.apply({'C': lambda x: x.values, 'D': lambda y: y.values})))[1]).values
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Can't believe all I had to do was drop the `.values`... Could've sworn I tried that. Anyway, thanks again!!